# Rearranging a file

Tags: python, file

I have a piece of code (seen below) which enables me to be able to ask pupils a series of random questions and then save their name and scores to a file. I combined the name and score into a single variable called info, with the name coming first then the score.  I now need to sort this information in order of score. Is there a way for me to make the score go in front of the name temporarily in the entire file so that I can use the sorted function to get it to go from lowest to highest?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thank you.

```
import random
import time

Name=input("What is your name?")
Class=input("Are you in Class A, B or C?")
print("Welcome" ,Name, "to the Maths Quiz!!")
time.sleep(3)
QuestionNumber=0
Operations=["+","-","x"]
answer=0
score=0
while QuestionNumber < 10:
        Num1=random.randint(1,12)
        Num2=random.randint(1,12)
        QuestionNumber=QuestionNumber+1
        operation = random.choice(Operations)
        print("What is", Num1 ,operation, Num2)
        guess=int(input("What is the answer to this question?"))

        if operation =="+":
            answer=Num1+Num2

        elif operation =="-":
                answer=Num1-Num2

        elif operation =="x":
            answer=Num1*Num2

        if guess==answer:
            score=score+1
            print ("Correct")
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

print("Well done You got", score, "Out of 10!!")
score=str((score))
Info= (Name + (" ") + score)
if Class=="A":
        ClassA=open("Class A Results.txt","a")
        ClassA.write(Info)
        ClassA.write(" \n")
        ClassA.close()
elif Class=="B":
        ClassB=open("Class B Results.txt","a")
        ClassB.write(Info)
        ClassB.write(" \n")
        ClassB.close()
elif Class=="C":
        ClassC=open("Class C Results.txt","a")
        ClassC.write(" \n")
        ClassC.write(Info)
        ClassC.close()

Viewscores=input("Do you want to see previous scores? Y/N")

if Viewscores=="Y":
        Classresults=input("Which Class would you like to see the results of?")
else:
        print ("Thank you for using the maths quiz, press enter to close the program in 10 seconds")
        time.sleep(10)
        closeprogram=input("Hit enter")
if Classresults=="A":
        ClassA=open("Class A Results.txt","r")
        Class=Class
        alphabet=ClassA.readlines()
        for line in sorted(alphabet):
                print(line)
elif Classresults=="B":
        ClassB=open("Class B Results.txt","r")
        Class=ClassB
        alphabet=ClassB.readlines()
        for line in sorted(alphabet):
                print(line)
elif Classresults=="C":
        ClassC=open("Class C Results.txt","r")
        Class=ClassC
        alphabet=ClassC.readlines()
        for line in sorted(alphabet):
                print(line)
else:
        print ("That is not valid")
```

Comment: Have a read of https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Comment: Also, don't name your variables things like `Class` (it's very close to the built-in `class` keyword, and avoid generic variable names like `Name` - something like `pupil_name` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted`'s `key` function can do this for you, but it's much nicer if you haven't combined them into a single string, but store `tuple`s of the pairs instead. Using `operator.itemgetter` generalizes nicely. Instead of storing:

```
score = str(score)
Info = Name + " " + score
```

store:

```
Info = (Name, score)  # Score remains a float
```

Then when you need to sort, do:

```
# Imports at top of file, not each sort
from operator import itemgetter

...

for name, score in sorted(myunorderedinfo, key=itemgetter(1, 0)):
```

In the code you provided, you're writing to a file and reading back (which would require reparsing), so you may want to look at the `csv` module to store the pairs with proper formatting (simple space separation is easy to mess up); you'd have to convert the inputs back to `float` in that case though, since `csv.reader` passes back `list`s of `str`, but that's relatively easy to do with a simple generator expression (left as an exercise).

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you could make your code much neater by removing all that duplicated code:

```
VALID_CLASS_NAMES = {"A", "B", "C"}

if Classresults not in VALID_CLASS_NAMES:
    print("Invalid class results selection")
    raise Exception("BOOM")

filename = "Class {} Results.txt".format(Classresults)
with open(filename, "r") as class_results_file:
    alphabet=class_results_file.readlines()
    for line in sorted(alphabet):
        print(line)
```

Now if you ever add class "D" then you just need to add it to the set of valid class names.